# Select the correct element

Tags: css, dom, css-selectors, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to setup with GTM a event when someone add this product to 'my favourite' section. I get all the elements to setup the event except the 'product name'.

The url is this -> https://www.silversanz.com/categoria/1/subcategoria/10/productos

Here are some code:

```
<article class="product cmp-product   " data-product-id="2166" data-gtm-name="Funda Shockwave anti-impactos iPad 9.7\&quot; Silver HT" data-gtm-id="111943640199" data-gtm-price="24.1879" data-gtm-brand="Silver HT" data-gtm-category="Apple-ipad" data-gtm-variant="" data-gtm-list="Fundas tablets" data-gtm-position="1" id="cmp-product_1" data-state="rendered">
    <a href="/producto/2166" class="product__content-link" title="Funda Shockwave anti-impactos iPad 9.7&quot; Silver HT">
      <section class="product__content">
        <div class="img-wrapper">
          <img alt="Funda Shockwave anti-impactos iPad 9.7&quot; Silver HT | Silver Sanz" src="//s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/silversanz.com/product_images/images/product_images_2533_grid.png?1548836431" class="">
        </div>
        <h4 class="title">Funda Shockwave anti-impactos iPad 9.7" Silver HT</h4>
      </section>
    </a>

<article class="product cmp-product   " data-product-id="519" data-gtm-name="Funda Wave azul marino para iPad Air 1,2, y iPad Pro 9,7\&quot;" data-gtm-id="111933840199" data-gtm-price="19.9892" data-gtm-brand="Silver HT" data-gtm-category="Apple-ipad" data-gtm-variant="" data-gtm-list="Fundas tablets" data-gtm-position="2" id="cmp-product_2" data-state="rendered">
    <a href="/producto/519" class="product__content-link" title="Funda Wave azul marino para iPad Air 1,2, y iPad Pro 9,7&quot;">
      <section class="product__content">
        <div class="img-wrapper">
          <img alt="Funda  iPad Air 1,2,  iPad Pro 9,7" src="//s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/silversanz.com/product_images/images/product_images_1378_grid.png?1528287248" class="">
        </div>
        <h4 class="title">Funda Wave azul marino para iPad Air 1,2, y iPad Pro 9,7"</h4>
      </section>
    </a>
```

With tihis code, I tried in GTM to make an Element Dom Variable to get the title with this element selector -> article#cmp-product_1.product.cmp-product

But my problem is that the number, in this case the 1, is depending of the product's position in the grid, therefore, with the 1, the variable only get the name of first grid product.

How can I get the product name correctly?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why don't you use without id, like this "article.product.cmp-product"

Comment: Because I got this result: 'Funda Shockwave anti-impactos iPad 9.7" Silver HT 24,19 € Producto añadido 24,1
9 € Añadir Producto agotado Destacado' is the name of first product of the grid and has more information about product..

Comment: I cannot see the attribute `id="cmp-product_1"` anywhere in the code (?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like your CSS to select any element which has an `id` which starts with

```
cmp-product_
```

then the selector is:

```
[id^="cmp-product_"]
```

In this case `^=` means ***any id*** beginning with these characters.

---

## Further Reading on Attribute Selectors:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors